# how to clone an object java

Tags: java, android, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to make a `DBManager` to allow connections to the DB, so here is the context.

I have an `abstract class Entitie`, that has the structure for every entitie in the DB, the important things in this case are the table name, the id, and an abstract method (`setContentValues`) that get the values from a `Cursor` and put them in variables (the method is abstract, beacause the variables changes dependig of what entitie is).

In the DBManager i have a method getAll, I pass a dummyEntitie that only has the id, and obviously, the class by default, has the table name.

So I try to build an `arraylist` of the same class entitie that the method recieve.
So, I have the idea, to clone the `dummyEntitie`, call the `setContentValues`, and add it to the `arraylist`.
But every time I tried to call the method `.clone`, I have an error on the IDE, so I don't know what is wrong, or how to clone the object.

Here is the code:

```
public ArrayList<Entitie> getAll(Entitie dummyEntitie){
    ArrayList<Entitie> entities = new ArrayList<Entitie>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + dummyEntitie.getTableName(); // Select All Query

    db = getWritableDb();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            try {
                dummyEntitie = dummyEntitie.clone();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dummyEntitie.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            dummyEntitie.setContentValues(cursor);
            entities.add(dummyEntitie);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return entities;
}
```

Comment: Make Your **Abstract class Entitie**  **cloneable** by implementing it. so all the **child class** of  **Entitie** will also be **cloneable**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify on your class that it implements [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface and you have to override `clone` method inside that class. By Default it will use `clone` method of `Object` class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the Cloneable interface?